# Selenium python click an element on facebook not work

Tags: python, selenium, click, element

I have a HTML code like this

```
<div class="_75e" id="u_0_1z">Invite friends to like this Page</div>
```

I would like to click on the link that has the text "Invite friends to like this Page". 
[image]

I tried the following way

```
driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1z").click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Invite friends to like this Page').click()
```

However, instead of clicking the link, the message box button is clicked

Like this
[image]

Could you help me solve this problem? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Facebook is designed in such a way that it thwarts such attempts to scrape and automate its use. You should strongly consider using the Facebook API, instead. That said, there's probably a container around the button you're looking for, which you should click instead of the underlying div with the text. You should also confirm that your `find_element_by` is appropriate for targeting the desired element.

Comment: I follow this tutorial https://pythonicways.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/invite-friends-to-your-facebook-page-with-python-selenium/ . And I tried use the code in this tutorial but it didn't work. I don't understand why they get the results as shown in video @@

Answer (score 0):

> `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Invite friends to like this Page').click()`

This definitely would not work since the "by link text" locator works for *links only* - `a` elements.

> `driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1z").click()`

This looks like it should match the element, but judging by the symptoms, there is an *another element with the same `id` on the page*.

I'd try with the "by xpath" option:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Invite friends to like this Page']").click()
```

---

You might also add an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) if you encounter any timing-related issues:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elm = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[. = 'Invite friends to like this Page']")))
elm.click()
```

Comment: I tried your code but Friend request button clicked instead @@

Comment: @RoboticVn are there any other `div` elements with `Invite friends to like this Page` text on the page?

Comment: There is only one

Comment: I follow this tutorial https://pythonicways.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/invite-friends-to-your-facebook-page-with-python-selenium/ but it doesn't work